# How to design data for complex recursive entities for persistence?

Tags: java, database, data-structures, spring-data-jpa

I was assuming that I have an entity as "Person".

```
{
  "UnqIdr": 125,
  "FrstNm": "Mark",
  "LastNm": "Antony",
  "Gndr": "Male",
  "DtOfBirth": "06-09-2020",
  "CtctDtls": {
  "Addr": [
    {
      "UnqIdr": "10001",
      "Ln1": "Street name",
      "Ln2": "Block Number",
      "Ln3": "Ward number",
      "Cty": "New York",
      "ZipCd": "60034",
      "Stat": "New Jersey",
      "Ctry": "North America",
      "IsPrmy": true
    }
  ],
    "PhneNb": [
      {
        "Nm": "Principal",
        "CtryCd": "+1",
        "Nb": "1234567890",
        "IsPrmy": true
      }
    ],
    "Email": "abc@def.com",
    "CtctURL": "www.def.com",
    "SclMdia": {
      "FacebookURL": "www.facebook.com/def",
      "LinkedInURL": "www.linkedin.com/us/def",
      "TwitterURL": "www.twitter.com/3634556"
    }
  },
  "IdntyProof": [{
    "UnqIdr": 16537,
    "Ctry": "India",
    "IdntyTp": 6548,
    "IdntyIdr": "INYHGB3462",
    "IsVerified": true,
    "VldFrm": "16-01-2000",
    "VldTill": "4-12-2023"
  }],
  "PrsnlIdnty": {
    "BldGrp": "A",
    "Id":[{
      "Nt": "Mole in right arm"
    }]
  },
  "Ethncty": "Nadar",
  "Rlgn": "Hindu",
  "Ntnlty": "Indian",
  "PrvsNtnlty": [{
    "Ntnlty": "Indian",
    "IdntyProof": [{
    "UnqIdr": 16537,
    "Ctry": "India",
    "IdntyTp": 6548,
    "IdntyIdr": "INYHGB3462",
    "IsVerified": true,
    "VldFrm": "16-01-2000",
    "VldTill": "4-12-2023"
    }]
  }],
  "MrtlSts": "Married",
  "Rltsh": [{
    "RltshTp": "Spouse",
    "UnqIdr": 134
  },{
    "RltshTp": "Divorcee",
    "UnqIdr": 130
  }]
}
```

However, the same information applies to an Employee, Customer and few more.

Structure of employee might be

```
{
  "UnqIdr": 125,
  "Department": "Chem Lab",
  "Person": {...}
}
```

However, when building the logic, we found an employee can also be a customer. Hence we thought of bundling as follows:

```
{
  //person-info
  "employee-info": {},
  "customer-info": {}
}
```

Now the problem comes up[ how to query with employee-info or customer-info.

I know it is data design; however, we are using Java 11 and Spring JPA for the same.

Additionally, which would be effective ways to design the solution. Even using NoSQL database is open for discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for data normalization with relational databases.

A simple solution is to store Person object in a different table and assigning it a personId field.

So the employee structure becomes:
{
  "UnqIdr": 125,
  "Department": "Chem Lab",
  "PersonId": 420
}

Comment: So we are on the right track.

Having specific domain objects with relational links is the correct mode?

Comment: That would be my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Relational databases are made for such data domains (eventual consistency for people....... no please).

Look here for some database design involving CUSTOMER and EMPLOYEE:

https://www.oracletutorial.com/getting-started/oracle-sample-database/

Now, you can still have Java inheritance regarding these People common attributes.